# Sort a list alphabetically with a specific value at head (if present)

Tags: java, sorting, java-8

I'm looking for the most readable definition for a comparator that satisfies the following test case:

```
@Test
public void testComparator() {
    List<String> toSort = Lists.newArrayList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f");
    Collections.shuffle(toSort);
    Comparator<String> theSolution = ???; 
    Collections.sort(toSort, theSolution);
    System.out.println(toSort); // Prints [c, a, b, d, e, f]
}
```

I've tried a comparator using Guava's Ordering defined like this:

```
Ordering.explicit("c").thenComparing(Ordering.natural());
```

However, explicit throws an exception for items not enumerated. So that solution fails. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

You could explicitly write a comparison function, e.g.

```
Comparator<String> theSolution = Comparator.comparing(a -> a.equals("c") ? "" : a);
// treat "c" as the same as the empty string "" when sorting which will be ranked first.
```

Comment: This only works if there are no empty strings in the array.

Answer (score 4):

It's unclear from your example if you want the members that are not "c" to remain in their current order or be sorted into alphabetical order. If you want to sort "c" to the front and leave the remainder then you could use:

```
Comparator.comparing("c"::equals).reversed();
```

Reversing the comparator is required because the natural ordering for a boolean is false first.

Sorting the remaining items in alphabetical order can be achieved by:

```
Comparator.comparing("c"::equals).reversed()
    .thenComparing(Object::toString, String::compareTo);
```

Comment: For the secondary sort you can use `.thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder())` or `.thenComparing(String::compareTo)`.

Comment: @shmosel I don't think so. Erasure has the type as `Comparator<Object>` rather than `Comparator<String>` at that point.

Comment: That's unfortunately true. You could fix it by doing `Comparator.comparing((String s) -> s.equals("c"))` or `Comparator.<String, Boolean>comparing("c"::equals)` but I'm not going to claim either of those are better options.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Guava, here's a solution using [`ComparisonChain`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ComparisonChain.html). I like that they're explicit about boolean precedence:

```
Comparator<String> theSolution = (a, b) -> ComparisonChain.start()
        .compareTrueFirst(a.equals("c"), b.equals("c"))
        .compare(a, b)
        .result();
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you may combine these tasks using a comparator chain like

```
List<String> toSort = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f");
Collections.shuffle(toSort);

toSort.sort(Comparator.comparing((String s) -> !s.equals("c"))
                      .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()));

System.out.println(toSort); // Prints [c, a, b, d, e, f]
```

but you may also consider just keeping these two tasks separated, sort first, move the desired values to the front afterwards:

```
List<String> toSort = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f");
Collections.shuffle(toSort);

toSort.sort(null);// null implies natural order
final int ix = toSort.indexOf("c");
if(ix>=0)
    Collections.rotate(toSort.subList(0, toSort.lastIndexOf("c")+1), -ix);

System.out.println(toSort); // Prints [c, a, b, d, e, f]
```

This also works with multiple occurrences.